# Adding an identifier to differentiate row based on its content in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am trying to write a code that add an identifer to each observation based on its content. The idea is to group each in one set until deregister is Yes

This is my data frame:

```
ID  Type    Registered DeRegister
P40 Review  Yes 
P40 Review      
P40 Review             Yes
P40 Review  Yes 
P40 Review             Yes
P41 Review  Yes 
P41 Review      
P41 Review             Yes
```

This is what I want to achieve:

```
ID  Type    Registered DeRegister Inditifier
P40 Review  Yes                   1
P40 Review                        1
P40 Review             Yes        1
P40 Review  Yes                   2
P40 Review             Yes        2
P41 Review  Yes                   1                 
P41 Review                        1
P41 Review             Yes        1
```

Have not tried and code yet, because I do not know how to do this. Can anybody please help me with that

Comment: Can you explain why rows 3 and 4 (identical first 4 columns) have a different `Inditifier`?

Comment: I have made chnages to the question, sorry about that

Answer (score 2):

If I'm interpreting your logic correctly, this is one way.

```r
library(dplyr)
x %>%
  group_by(ID, Type) %>%
  mutate(Inditifier = 1L + lag(cumsum(DeRegister == "Yes"), default = FALSE)) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 8 x 5
#   ID    Type   Registered DeRegister Inditifier
#   <chr> <chr>  <chr>      <chr>           <int>
# 1 P40   Review Yes        No                  1
# 2 P40   Review No         No                  1
# 3 P40   Review No         Yes                 1
# 4 P40   Review Yes        No                  2
# 5 P40   Review No         Yes                 2
# 6 P41   Review Yes        No                  1
# 7 P41   Review No         No                  1
# 8 P41   Review No         Yes                 1
```

And using `data.table`, if that's your preference:

```r
library(data.table)
DT <- x
setDT(DT)
DT[, Inditifier := 1L + shift(cumsum(DeRegister == "Yes"), fill = FALSE), by = c("ID", "Type")]
```

And finally, base R:

```r
do.call(
  rbind.data.frame,
  by(x, x[,c("ID", "Type")], function(z) {
    Ind <- c(1L, 1L + cumsum(z$DeRegister == "Yes"))
    transform(z, Inditifier = Ind[-length(Ind)])
  }))
```

---

Data:

```r
x <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactor=FALSE, text="
ID  Type    Registered DeRegister
P40 Review  Yes        No
P40 Review  No         No
P40 Review  No         Yes
P40 Review  Yes        No
P40 Review  No         Yes
P41 Review  Yes        No
P41 Review  No         No
P41 Review  No         Yes")
```

Comment: Nart Razak, does this answer your question? If so, please "accept" it. If not, edit your question with updates that explain why it does not work.

Comment: Nart, I recognize that you changed the source data in your question, so while my suggested method works without change, I've updated the answer to reflect your change. Does it resolve your question?